# For Loop Not Working With pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I am using pandas to read some csv files and ran into an error.

I have this list of files that I want to read:

```
files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
```

When I do this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('file1.csv').head()
pd.read_csv('file2.csv').head()
pd.read_csv('file3.csv').head()
```

everything works fine. This is obviously not want I want to do however. I was thinking this would work:

```
import pandas as pd
for file in files:
   pd.read_csv(file).head()
```

but when I run this code, I get nothing.

I'm confident that this is not an error with my files list or anything like that, because when I do this:
import pandas as pd
for i in range(2):
pd.read_csv('file1.csv').head()

I get nothing, instead of the expected first 5 rows of file1.csv twice.

Why is this happening?

Note: I'm using Jupyter notebook so I don't have to print the head or anything like that, it automatically comes up when I do `pd.read_csv('file1.csv').head()`

Comment: You should either display the results with `print()` as you go through the list of files or save them in a variable (a list) and display later. Function call results are shown automatically only in the interactive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe everything works fine in your code.
In Jupyter notebook, it doesn't always print the result automatically.

If you want to check how Jupyter notebook prints the result, check the following code:

```
x = [1,2]
x
```

This will show the result [1,2]

```
len(x)
```

And this will show 2

```
for i in range(3):
    len(x)
```

On the other hand, this will not show anything.

Please consider to save the result inside the for loop, or print each time in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
res = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # print(df.head())   if you insist.
    res.append(df)
```

Now you can do whatever you like with the list of dataframes in res. Lets just concatenate them:

```
df = pd.concat(res)
```

Or maybe all you need to see it all works is:

```
import pandas as pd
for file in files:
    print(pd.read_csv(file).head())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, I would strongly suggest you to enter the entire file path to the file instead of just mentioning the file name

```
import pandas as pd

files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']

for file in files:
   temp = pd.read_csv(file)
   print(temp.head())
```